# Fill area under the curve - R plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon

I am trying to fill the area under the plot curve with color. This is my data:

```
WOL EB1 EB2 EB3
-4  -9.61818    5.38182 15.38182
-3  -11.75152   3.24848 13.24848
-2  -13.01212   1.98788 11.98788
-1  -16.16364   -1.16364    8.83636
1   -33.8606    -18.8606    -8.8606
2   -27.897 -12.897 -2.897
3   -25.4242    -10.4242    -0.4242
4   -23.09697   -8.09697    1.90303
5   -21.01212   -6.01212    3.98788
6   -18.73333   -3.73333    6.26667
7   -16.45455   -1.45455    8.54545
8   -16.06667   -1.06667    8.93333
9   -15.193939  -0.193939   9.806061
10  -14.175758  0.824242    10.824242
11  -12.13939   2.86061 12.86061
12  -11.84848   3.15152 13.15152
```

My code is:

```
cord.x <- c(eb$WOL)
cord.y <- c(eb$EB1)
polygon(cord.x,cord.y,col='red',border = NA)
```

But this fill the area above and I could not find the way to do the area under.
I also try the plotly package but without success.
My wish is to have three curves (WOL~EB1; WOL~EB2; and WOL~EB3) and three corresponding areas with different colors.

Can you please help.
Many thanks,
Phuong

Comment: Just a tip, you can use `dput(eb)` to print an easily shareable version of your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `gather` with `dplyr`, and then use `ggplot`:

```
require(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(iv, value, -WOL) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=WOL, y=value)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill=iv))
```

[image: stacked]

**Update** (per comments)

By default, `geom_area()` has `position="stacked"`, which may make it seem like values are distorted on the y-axis.  You can use `position="dodge"` instead, or even `geom_polygon()`, for different effects:

**geom_area(position="dodge")**

```
df %>%
  gather(iv, value, -WOL) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=WOL, y=value, fill=iv)) +
  geom_area(position=position_dodge(0), alpha=.7)
```

[image: dodge]
**geom_polygon()**

```
df %>%
  gather(iv, value, -WOL) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=WOL, y=value, fill=iv)) +
  geom_polygon()
```

[image: polygon]

Comment: Wow, this is perfectly what I wanted. Thanks andrew

Comment: You're welcome!  If this answer resolved your question, please mark it accepted by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.  (You can upvote too, if you feel it's appropriate.)

Comment: Hi Andrew: how come EB3, has some values smaller than EB2? The data shows not! It should be well above the area of EB2?

Comment: It's not that the values are higher, it's just that the levels are stacked.  Like in a stacked bar chart.  You can change the `position` parameter to adjust this.  You can also use `geom_polygon` instead.  I'll update my answer with examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `ggplot2` package in R to achieve what you are asking. Here's the code which will produce the plot below (which I believe is what you're looking for: a curve with the area under it shaded):

```
data<-data.frame(cbind(WOL,EB1,EB2,EB3))
library(ggplot2)
g<-ggplot(data=data,aes(x=WOL,y=EB1))+
  geom_line() + 
  geom_ribbon(data = data[data$WOL<max(data$WOL),],aes(x=WOL,ymax=EB1),ymin=0,fill="red", alpha=0.5)+
  ggtitle("WOL vs EB1")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
g
```

[image]
Do the same for EB2 & EB3.

Comment: this is what I got when using polygon but what I wanted is to fill the area which is current 'grey" in the plot you created. Sorry I did not make it clear in the question

Comment: don't you think that area extends to the -ve y-direction and you want to shade that? I don't think it'll be a closed area that you can shade. It has to be a bounded area.

Comment: I just looked again the answer of Andrew above, yes, you are right. I made a mistake. It should be bounded area. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want interactive plot (you mentioned `plotly`), here is a solution using the [`highcharter`](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/showcase.html) package

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

eb <- read.table(text = "WOL EB1 EB2 EB3
                  -4  -9.61818    5.38182 15.38182
                 -3  -11.75152   3.24848 13.24848
                 -2  -13.01212   1.98788 11.98788
                 -1  -16.16364   -1.16364    8.83636
                 1   -33.8606    -18.8606    -8.8606
                 2   -27.897 -12.897 -2.897
                 3   -25.4242    -10.4242    -0.4242
                 4   -23.09697   -8.09697    1.90303
                 5   -21.01212   -6.01212    3.98788
                 6   -18.73333   -3.73333    6.26667
                 7   -16.45455   -1.45455    8.54545
                 8   -16.06667   -1.06667    8.93333
                 9   -15.193939  -0.193939   9.806061
                 10  -14.175758  0.824242    10.824242
                 11  -12.13939   2.86061 12.86061
                 12  -11.84848   3.15152 13.15152",
                 header = TRUE)

eb %>% 
  gather(iv, value, -WOL) -> eb_long
str(eb_long)
#> 'data.frame':    48 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ WOL  : int  -4 -3 -2 -1 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
#>  $ iv   : chr  "EB1" "EB1" "EB1" "EB1" ...
#>  $ value: num  -9.62 -11.75 -13.01 -16.16 -33.86 ...

hchart(eb_long, "polygon", hcaes(x = WOL, y = value, 
                                 group = iv,
                                 color = iv, 
                                 fill  = iv))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).